# Jquery ajax using asp.net does not work on IE9 during the 2nd call of the function?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have gridview that is loaded from another aspx page after an ajax call, the problem is it works on chrome/firefox/safari but using ie9 the ajax call would work fine during the first call but when i try to call the function again it throws an 304 status on the network tab of ie9 dev tool and the gridview is not refreshed.

Here is the jquery code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LoadCoursesGridViewHere.aspx.cs" Inherits="CoursesGridView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


                <div id="Gridview-container">
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>

                <%-- <asp:Button Text="text" ID="btn" OnClientClick=" __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '')" runat="server" />--%>
                <input type="button" id="btn" value="insert"/>



    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#btn").click(function () {
            var a = $("#TextBox1").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'WebService.asmx/insert',
                data: "{ 'name': '" + a + "' }",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                success: function () {

                    // alert('insert was performed.');
                    $("#Gridview-container").empty();
                    $("#Gridview-container").load("GridViewCourses.aspx #GridView1");



                }
            });

        });


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What happen is that after click the button it will insert the textbox value in the database through the webservice 'insert' and then reload the gridview that is placed inside a different aspx page. The problem is that when I ran it on IE9 during the 1st insert everything works properly but the succeeding inserts does reload the gridview and I noticed that it says '304' on the network tab of ie9 dev tool.

Comment: 304 means it's getting it from cache.. You just need to set your cache to false in your ajax call or do an `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});`

Comment: @wirey Thank you for the immediate reply now it's working, but the thing is earlier I tried putting cache: fasle paramater inside the ajax call along with the other parameters and did not work but when I tried $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); it's now working. why is like that? :D

Comment: I think because `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});` sets all ajax calls cache to false.. therefore your .load call isn't cached also..  When you just put it inside the ajax call, only that cache is set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Response 304](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E304.html) means it's getting it from cache.. You just need to set your cache to false in your ajax call or do an

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); // this will set all ajax calls caching to false
```